# java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:2222" "listen,resolve")

Tags: java, rmi

```
System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        final int port = 2222;
        try {
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(PORT);
            StubRealize stub = new StubRealize();
            Stub serverStub = (Stub) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(stub, PORT);
            registry.rebind("Stub", serverStub);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Server started...");
```

Пытаюсь запустить rmi сервер с политикой:

```
grant {
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:2222", "listen, resolve";
}
```

Путь указан верно. Выдает ошибку:

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:2222" "listen,resolve")   at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
>     at
>   java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
>     at
>   java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
>     at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkListen(SecurityManager.java:1131)
>     at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:374)    at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:237)   at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:128)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createServerSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:45)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createServerSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:345)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:666)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:330)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:249)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:411)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147)     at
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:236)
>     at
>   java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(UnicastRemoteObject.java:383)
>     at
>   java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(UnicastRemoteObject.java:320)

VM параметры:

```
-Djava.security.policy=src\main\resources\server.policy;
```

Спасибо.

Решение:

```
System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "src\\main\\resources\\server.policy");
```

Comment: Мой [прошлый ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/758316/204271) вам не помог?

Comment: он вызвал эту проблему, сервер не запускается

Comment: Попробуйте абсолютный путь к политике указать, от корня.

Comment: Пробовал, это не помогло.

Comment: Удалил VM параметры... Добавил решение проблемы.

Comment: На самом деле я не до конца разобрался почему тот вариант не работает...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте создать рядом файл unsecure.policy со следующим содержимым

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

и указать его JVM следующим образом

```
java -Djava.security.policy==src\main\resources\unsecure.policy ...
```

(обратите внимания на два знака равенства)